# Player 1 and Player 2 toss n and m fair dice respectively. What is the probability that there's no single coincidence between their results.

Tags: probability, dice

Coincidences **within** results of each player are possible.

Example of "successful" event (n=m=3): {1,1,6} and {3,4,5} (no coincidences)

Example of "unsuccessful" event (n=m=3): {1,2,6} and {2,4,5} (1 coincidence - "2")

> *My guess is that $$prob=(5/6)^{m*n}$$, but when I run a simulation program, I get a result slightly different from "theoretical" one.*

Answer (score 2):

Your expected result has two problems:  There are $nm$ pairs of dice, each of which might match, so you might expect the chance to be $(\frac 56)^{nm}$.  The equivalent for $s$ sided dice of $(\frac{s-1}s)^{mn}$ would be pretty close if $s$ is very large.  The other is that when one player has matching dice, there are less opportunities for a match.

What you need to do is calculate the chance that each player has $1,2,...,6$ different numbers.  For $n=m=3$, each player has one number $\frac 6{216}$ of the time, two different numbers $\frac {90}{216}$ of the time, and three different numbers $\frac {120}{216}$ of the time.  The chance of no match is then $\frac 1{216^2}(6*6*\frac 56+2*6*90*\frac 46+2*6*120*\frac 36+90*90*\frac{6}{15}+2*90*120*\frac 3{15}+120*120*\frac 1{20})=\frac{1625}{7776}\approx 0.2090$

Comment: Ross, thanks. But I'm afraid I didn't get it. Do you mind to expand  a bit more on how you came to this expression?  I've tried to generate straightforwardly all possible combinations of 3x3 throws and got 9750 combinations with no match from 46656 totally possible. It gives probability ~0.2089763 . It correlates pretty good with "experimental" results when I just generate randomly 2 sets with 10000 throws of 3 dice in each and count number of no matches between these sets.

Comment: @Dmitry: the second term $\frac 1{216}^2(2*6*120*\frac 36)$ the $\frac 1{216^2}$ is the total number of throws.  I am calculating the chance one player has three dice the same, the other has two dice the same, and there is no match.  The 2 comes because either player can have all the same, there are $6$ ways to have three the same, $90$ ways to have two the same, and $\frac 46$ is the chance of no match.  The other terms are similar.

Comment: @Dmitry:  but I realized my later terms for no match are not correct.  The $\frac {12}{36}$ for two vs two should be $\frac {4 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2}=\frac {6}{15}$  I will correct it.  It now matches your result nicely.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!